# Why am I getting an error when using \renewcommand, here?

Tags: macros, errors

I try to type `\renewcommand{\mr}{\mathrm}`, so that I can then use `\mr` in my text instead of `\mathrm`. I get the error `\mr Undefined`. what is going on?

Comment: That `\mr` is not defined and you should use `\newcommand{\mr}{\mathrm}` instead.

Comment: so is it right that renewcommand takes a predfined command in the second bracket and needs to have also a predefined command in the frist bracket, and that newcommand takes a predefined command in the second bracket and takes an anonymous, not predefined command in the first bracket?

Comment: No. It's not the way it works. The first argument to `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` is the command to be (re)defined; in the second argument you specify what the command should be replaced with.

Comment: in \newcommand{\mr}{\mathrm}, i am taking the already predefined \mathrm and wanting it to be defined as the shorter \mr so that i can use \mr throughout the document. you now seem to be saying the opposite. \mr is not the command to be redefined; it is what the command \mathrm should be replaced with

Comment: @inquiries I think you are misunderstanding 'replaced' here. TeX is a macro expansion language, so with `\newcommand{\mr}{\mathrm}` when LaTeX finds `\mr` in your source it replaces it with `\mathrm`, then looks up the definition of `\mathrm`, _etc._

Answer (score 5):

TeX uses macro replacement as its fundamental concept. When you say

```
\newcommand{\foo}{<whatever>}
```

you're instructing the program to replace every occurrence of `\foo` with `<whatever>`. In order for that `\newcommand` to work, the command `\foo` must be undefined at the moment `\newcommand` is performed.

So with

```
\newcommand{\mr}{\mathrm}
```

you are basically creating an alias for `\mathrm`: upon finding `\mr` in the input stream, TeX will replace `\mr` with `\mathrm` and then `\mathrm` with its definition and so on until only “purely executable” commands remain, that TeX passes on for further processing in what is usually called the “stomach”.

If the command `\foo` already had a definition, you need to use `\renewcommand` (but be always afraid of using it).

The second argument to `\newcommand` needn't be just a single token: you may as well define

```
\newcommand{\independence}{When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.}
```

and upon finding `\independence`, TeX will replace it with that text.

You find much more in chapter 8 of [“LaTeX for complete novices”](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)